# How to detect street name plates

Tags: object-detection

I have some problems with this assignment. Given an image of a street nameplate, like this one

[image: http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/45921/CARTELLO_VIA_R_600.jpg]

I have to detect the nameplate and mark it on the image with a rectangle, obtaining something like this:

[image]

Nameplates can be rotated, scaled and in different lighting conditions. The procedure must be automatic.

What i have tried so far is to isolate the nameplate from the background. I've tried with different thresholding methods, but the problem is that i have different images and one single method doesn't work with all of them, due to different lighting condition and noise. What i've thought is to perform a pre-processing on the images, to reduce noise and normalize light, but, again, how to choose pre-processing steps that work with every image in my dataset? And what for images that don't need pre-processing?

Another problem is that there might be other signs in the image with writings on them and i have to ignore them. So i've thought i could isolate the nameplate by that blue outline, but i don't know if that can be done(or if it is convenient) with template matching, also considering that part of the outline could be cut off from the image.

So what i'm asking is: is there an automatic way to isolate/detect only that type of nameplates that have the blue outline on them, regardless of orientation, light conditions, shadows on them, noise in the image, etc? What steps would you follow?

Thank You

Comment: Most object detection converts images to grayscale, so if you **really** need to retain the color detection, you need to search specifically for that.

Comment: actually i'm not interested in color detection, but i was looking for some feature that could help me to detect the name plate. For example if i try to start with a gray level threshold, in this particular image i also get the sky segmented out.

Comment: What the similar objects you're trying to not find?  Are they the same shape as these?  If they aren't and you pass enough information, you should be able to accurately detect your desired signs.  Trust the algorithm to find features that help it distinguish.  Your job is to provide enough images to it.

Comment: Wait, you don't even mention OpenCV.  How are you going about this?  Check out this tutorial I wrote on detecting objects with OpenCV: johnallen.github.io/opencv-object-detection-tutorial.  This could help but it will not allow you to detect signs "regardless of orientation", unless you provide it probably thousands of images of rotated signs.

Comment: I have to do this in matlab, i didn't add matlab as a tag because i am searching for general image-processing steps to develop into code, rather than code itself. Anyway do you think that the best way to solve this problem is using a classifier?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best. I think it's one way of detecting these signs.

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try! Thank you!